# How can I format a difftime() value like this : Y:M:W:D:H:S

Tags: r, time, lubridate, difftime

I currently use the `difftime()` function to get the elapsed time between two `Sys.time()` objects.

ie :

```
t1 <- Sys.time()
t2 <- Sys.time()
elapsed_time <- difftime(t2, t1)
```

The current output is something like :

`5.188578 days`

I would like to get an output that show the elapsed time this way :

`5 days : 4 hours : 30 mins : 15 secs`

or something similar to this.

I already tried the `strptime()` function, but it seems to work for dates so I'm not sure how I could use it.

I also looked at the lubridate `periods()` functions that seems to give output like this : **"3m 12d 0H 0M 0S"** (which would be great) but it doesn't seems to work with my elapsed_time object.

I also looked on stackoverflow and google but didn't find the answer I wanted.

so I was wondering if anyone could give me some clues on how to proceed.
Thank you.

**Edit : I found a somewhat good answer With Dave's comment and [How to get time differences with output having multiple units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328410/how-to-get-time-differences-with-output-having-multiple-units/55328744#55328744) page.**

```
library(lubridate)
t1 <- Sys.time()
t2 <- Sys.time()
elapsed_time <- difftime(t2, t1)

as.period(elapsed_time)
```

Output result format is :

```
"3H 37M 55S"
```

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328410/how-to-get-time-differences-with-output-having-multiple-units/55328744#55328744

Comment: Thanks Dave, seems like I just had to do as.period(elapsed_time) to make it work. Not sure why it didn't work when I tried it, I probably did a mistake. The output is not 100% what I want but it is still good enough. Thank you.